# Randomness test using rngtest

Tags: command-line

I have a binary sequence like 
0011000111000111. I put this in a file
abc.txt. I want to test its randomness using rngtest.

I am getting as follows:

```
/Documents$ rngtest <abc.txt> 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Please help me.

```
I am getting this after using rngtest <abc.txt. 
Is it random? 


rngtest <abc.txt 
rngtest 5
Copyright (c) 2004 by Henrique de Moraes Holschuh
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

rngtest: starting FIPS tests...
rngtest: entropy source drained
rngtest: bits received from input: 16000
rngtest: FIPS 140-2 successes: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2 failures: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Monobit: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Poker: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Runs: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Long run: 0
rngtest: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Continuous run: 0
rngtest: input channel speed: (min=0.000; avg=0.000; max=0.000)bits/s
rngtest: FIPS tests speed: (min=0.000; avg=0.000; max=0.000)bits/s
rngtest: Program run time: 173 microseconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ">" after the .txt.

`rngtest < abc.txt`